# What is the link to log out on Wordpress?

Tags: logout

I have a custom login form that takes the code from wp-login.php.

I can't use wp-login.php because when this file is used I refer them to my main login file, ie login.php.

Is there therefore a link or function that I can use to log out via the login.php page and not wp-login.php?

I also tried to use the following code but without success:

> https://example.com/login.php?action=logout

Thanks to those who will help me.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried to modify the following function and then apply it to a menu item but it still doesn't work.

```
function wp_new_logout_url( $redirect = '' ) {
    $args = array( 'action' => 'logout' );
    if ( ! empty( $redirect ) ) {
        $args['redirect_to'] = urlencode( $redirect );
    }

    $logout_url = add_query_arg( $args, site_url( 'login.php', 'login' ) );
    $logout_url = wp_nonce_url( $logout_url, 'log-out' );

    return apply_filters( 'logout_url', $logout_url, $redirect );
}
```

This is where it is applied:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_new_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code on your login.php?action=logout page can call [wp_logout()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout/) to log out.

You probably also want to hook the [logout_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/logout_url) filter to generate your new logout URL, else menu bars and the admin site will still try to use wp_login.php.

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for the reply